# How to work with Interpolating Function?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm starting using Mathematica. I have two coupled differential equations and after using NDSolve the output is in the form of a Interpolating Function. I want to Plot the square modulus of one of the two solutions, but after several trials the plot is still empty. I want to know how to work with this function.

```
sol = NDSolve[{a1'[t] == -I*V12*Exp[-I*w21*t]*a2[t], 
 a2'[t] == -I*V21*Exp[I*w21*t]*a2[t], a1[0] == 1, a2[0] == 0},
 {a1, a2}, {t, 40}] 

(* {{a1->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,40.}},"<>"],
  a2->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,4‌​0.}},"<>"]}}    *)  

f1=a1->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,40.}},"<>"]      

f2 = Conjugate[fun] // ComplexExpand 
f3 = fun*gun Plot[f3, {t, 0, 40}]
```

Where `fun` is `f1` and `gun` is `f2`.

Comment: Post the code of your attempts.

Comment: sol = NDSolve[{a1'[t] == -I*V12*Exp[-I*w21*t]*a2[t], 
   a2'[t] == -I*V21*Exp[I*w21*t]*a2[t], a1[0] == 1, a2[0] == 0}, {a1, 
   a2}, {t, 40}]

{{a1->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,40.`}},"<>"],a2->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,40.`}},"<>"]}}

Comment: f1=a1->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.`,40.`}},"<>"]

Comment: f2 = Conjugate[fun] // ComplexExpand
f3 = fun*gun
Plot[f3, {t, 0, 40}]

I think I have no idea what I am doing

Comment: I'm sorry fun is f1 and gun is f2

Comment: You should edit your question and put the code in it rather than in comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Answer (score 5):

I can't make heads or tails of above, but perhaps this will get you started. *Read* the documentation - it's your best source of information.

First, let's get some solution from `NDSolve` :

```
sol =  NDSolve[{u''[t] + u[t] == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 1}, u, {t, 0, \[Pi]}]

(* {{u->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,3.14159}},<>]}} *)
```

So, `NDSolve` has given us a set of `Rules` (in this case, just one) that maps the solution for *u* to an `InterpolatingFunction`. Read the documentation re: rules if you are new to the concept.

So, we'll take that rule and extract the function itself into a convenient name:

```
interpFN = u /. First@sol

(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,3.14159}},<>] *)
```

We can use this (pretty much) like any other function:

```
interpFN[2]
(* 0.909297 *)
```

And plot it in the same way:

```
Plot[interpFN[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Hope that helped somewhat...

Comment: Thanks for answer!, but what about if I want to plot the square modulus of "u" assuming that is a complex function? I can conjugate individual points of the Interpolating function, but I fail conjugating the whole function